# non static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

My line sb.init(this); always comes back with a "non static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context."  I cant figure out why.

```
package asteroidgame;

import blobmx.BlobGUI;
import blobmx.SandBox;
import blobmx.SandBoxMode;
import java.util.Random;

public class AsteroidGame implements BlobGUI{

private static final Random random = new Random();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AsteroidGame();
}    
public static void AsteroidGame(){ 
    SandBox sb = new SandBox();
    sb.setSandBoxMode(SandBoxMode.FLOW);
    sb.setFrameRate(66);
    sb.init(this);
}
```

Comment: What do you think `this` is should be referring to and why do you think so?

Comment: PLEASE google it !!! You will find at least 1000 questions with same title.

Comment: It looks like that's meant to be a constructor? If so, remove the words `static void`.

Comment: I spent at least an hour googling threads just like this one.  Did not help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AsteroidGame();
}
```

to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AsteroidGame myAsteroidGame = new AsteroidGame();
}
```

then do whatever you want to do with `myAsteroidGame` (such as calling the method or whatever you want)

Answer (score 1):

**`this` cannot be used inside static method.** As there is no instance representation inside the static method.

Comment: pbabcdefp was right about it being a constructor.  I removed the static void part and it fixed the first problem but now my call to the constructor says it cannot find the symbol: AsteroidGame()

Answer (score 0):

This was the fix:

```
package asteroidgame;

import blobmx.BlobGUI;
import blobmx.SandBox;
import blobmx.SandBoxMode;
import java.util.Random;


public class AsteroidGame implements BlobGUI{

private static final Random random = new Random();
public static final SandBox sb = new SandBox();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AsteroidGame newgame = new AsteroidGame();
}    
public AsteroidGame(){ 
    //SandBox sb = new SandBox();
    sb.setSandBoxMode(SandBoxMode.FLOW);
    sb.setFrameRate(66);
    sb.init(this);
}
```